# C - Threads generating same random value

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have to do a program that simulate the movement of some cars using 4 threads. Each one of them have to select a random car from a string and call a function to concatenate "buffer_resultados".

All the simulation functions are working correctly, the problem is every thread is generating the same random number, so it's the same car everytime.

Another thing is that I must use system calls to open and write in files, so I'm using write() to write the content of buffer_resultados in my .dat file.

The first time it goes well, but the second one it doesn't write a line that should be at the top of Buffer_resultados.

This is my code, I'm completelly new to C and threads, so it's possible it isn't correct, Thanks.

```
char caracteristicas_deportivos[NUMERO_MODELOS_DEPORTIVOS][64]={"Aston Martin Vantage V12|07.7|090",
"Ferrari LaFerrari|09.6|111",
"Lamborgini Aventador|09.6|097",
"Porshe 911 turbo S|09.6|092",
"Tesla Model S|10.0|069",
"Hennessey Venom GT|10.3|120",
"Bugatti Chiron|11.2|114",
"Koenigsegg Agera|10.3|121"};

/*string que contendrÃ¡ el mensaje a escribir en el fichero*/
char mensaje_final[TAM_MENSAJE_FINAL];

/* Resto del cÃ³digo, variables globales, funciones y funciÃ³n principal o main*/ 
//Per buffer result final
char buffer_resultados[TAM_MENSAJE_FINAL];
//Per guardar valors cotxe amb strtk_r i buffer result
char buffer_cadena[1000];
char delim[4]="|";
char cadena[1000];
char *save=cadena;
char *snom;
char *sacc;
char *svmax;
char *resultats;
double acc;
double vmax;
//Per threads
int comptador=0;
int numrandom;
//Per llegir el fitxer
ssize_t nbytes;
int descf;
//Inicialitza el semafor de threads
pthread_mutex_t mutex;


//Funcio dels THREADS
void *generar_simulacio(void* dades){   
    //Generem un numero random
    numrandom=rand() % NUMERO_MODELOS_DEPORTIVOS;

    strcpy(cadena, caracteristicas_deportivos[numrandom]); //Guardem copia caracteristicas_deportivos perque es modificara amb el strtok_r
    snom=strtok_r(cadena, delim, &save);;
    sacc=strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save);
    svmax=strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save);

    acc = atof(sacc);
    vmax = atof(svmax);

    //INICI ZONA EXCLUSIO MUTUA
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    //#### S'inicia el semafor, aqui actua 1 sol thread alhora #### 
    comptador++;
    char buffer_cadena[1000];
    strcpy(buffer_cadena, "");
    strcat(buffer_cadena, "Cotxe: ");
    strcat(buffer_cadena, snom);
    strcat(buffer_cadena, ", Acc: ");
    strcat(buffer_cadena, sacc);
    strcat(buffer_cadena, ", Vmax: ");
    strcat(buffer_cadena, svmax);
    strcat(buffer_cadena, ", Distancia: ");
    strcat(buffer_cadena, "1000\n");
    strcat(buffer_resultados, buffer_cadena); //Afegim la linia generada al buffer_resultats
    movimiento_mrua(INTERVALO_TIEMPO, acc, vmax, DISTANCIA, buffer_resultados);
    strcat(buffer_resultados, "\n");
    //Trucada al sistema per guardar valors simulacio al fitxer 
    nbytes = write(descf, buffer_resultados, TAM_MENSAJE_FINAL);
    if(nbytes==-1){
        printf("No s'ha pogut escriure al fitxer.");
        printf("%s\n", buffer_resultados);
    }
    else{
        printf("Soc el thread n: %d. He escrit al archiu.\n", comptador);
        printf("Nrand: %d \\\\ c: %s, a: %f, v: %f\n", numrandom, snom, acc, vmax);
    }
    //Para el semafor, tots els threads funcionen alhora
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //FI ZONA EXCLUSIO MUTUA
    strcpy(buffer_resultados, "");
}


//Inicialització del generador de numeros random
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    double temps1=devolver_tiempo(); //Calcula el temps inicial per saber quan tarda en executar-se

    //Obrim el fitxer
    descf = open("salida_deportivos_threads.dat", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU); //O_creat crea arxiu, O_TRUNC borra tot lo de dins de l'arxiu, O_WRONLY permet escriure || S_IRWXU dona permisos a l'usuari a fer-ho tot.
    if (descf == -1){
        printf("Error al obrir l'archiu.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Fitxer obert.\n");
    }

    srand(2*(time(NULL) + getpid())+1);
    //Creem els 4 threads
    pthread_t thread_id[2];
    pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,(void*)generar_simulacio,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,(void*)generar_simulacio,NULL);

    /*
    if((pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,(void*)generar_simulacio,NULL)!=0)||(pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,(void*)generar_simulacio,NULL)!=0))
    {
        printf("ERROR al crear los threads \n");
        return (-1);
    } */

    //Esperem a que tots els threads acabin
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL);
    }

    double temps2=devolver_tiempo();
    double texecucio=(temps2-temps1)/1000000;
    printf("Temps d'execucio: %.4f segons.\n", texecucio);
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: You are using the same variables for all threads. (I.e. `numrandom` is defined as a global variable). Define a dedicated local copy of all variables in each thread.

Comment: How I understand the code, the threads are calling the generar_simulacio function, and this one generates a new random number everytime.

Where would I have to create those local copies of the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the C11 [§7.22.2.1 The `rand` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.1) is not required to be thread-safe:

> The rand function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions.

However, as noted by [Frankie_C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157478/frankie-c) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795541/c-threads-generating-same-random-value#comment94440869_53795541), you aren't necessarily running into that problem directly — your code is using a single global variable `numrandom` in both threads without any protection (a mutex, for example, or make the variable non-global).

The 'obvious' fix is to make `numrandom` into a variable that's local to the thread function (and remove the now unused global variable).

```
void *generar_simulacio(void* dades){   
    //Generem un numero random
    int numrandom = rand() % NUMERO_MODELOS_DEPORTIVOS;
```

That would probably suffice for your purposes.  However, you also need to review all the other global variables and most of them also need to become local variables in the thread function.

Strictly, you should also create and use a mutex to protect calls to `srand()` and `rand()`.  Or you need to use an alternative random number generator where each thread can have its own independent sequence of random numbers, such as POSIX [`nrand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nrand48.html) (or `jrand48()`).
You'd still need thread-local storage for the seed material — that would be a local variable in the thread function unless you have very specific reasons to do something more complicated.

Global modifiable variables make threaded code harder — you have to coordinate access to them, for reading and writing, often with a mutex or some similar construct.  Global constants (read-only variables) aren't a problem.

Comment: Thanks! You made yourself very clear! I have it working now but I found another problem.

The point of this exercise is to see how using threads can make a program run faster. 
The problem is that I have the same program runing without threads and last 5 to 6 seconds, just the same than the threads one.

I'm thinking that if the threads do all of the code inside the mutex, becouse it has to be protected, there is just no point in using them.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't gain any benefit from threads unless the threads can run concurrently, and if they're perpetually holding a mutex that prevents any other thread from running, then you're going to see a slow down, not a speed up.  You shouldn't need many mutexes.  If you stick with `rand()`, you probably need one for that.  I'm not sure about the `comptador` counter; that may need one too — though I've not scrutinized it at all thoroughly — it isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]).  But the rest of the code shouldn't need mutexes that I can see.

Comment: The streams library (`fprintf()` et al) provide thread-safe access at the per-call level.  You can look up POSIX [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and `funlockfile()` if you want to group I/O calls at the thread-level.  Using repeated `strcat()` calls leads to quadratic behaviour.  Your strings may be short enough that it isn't a major problem, but look at [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) instead.